# Best way to get a list of lists output with itertools

Tags: python, python-itertools

**Summary: Is there a way to change the output format of itertools from list of tuples to list of lists, similar to making parameter changes using matplotlib.rcParams for matplotlib?**

I want to find all possible combinations of elements of a set A with repeats allowed as long as the specific combination is not an element of another set B, in the form of list of lists. The rest of the code works with lists rather than tuples, so it looks more suitable for my preference.

I have this short code snippet, utilising the list comprehension.

```py
    A=list(range(5))
    B=[[0,1],[1,2]]
    C=list([list(i)  for i in itertools.product(A, A) if i not in B])
```

While this works alright and certainly presentable, I feel it might be slow. I also dropped itertools for double for looped list comprehension.

```py
    A=list(range(5))
    B=[[0,1],[1,2]]
    C=[[i,j] for i in A for j in A if [i,j] not in B]
```

This doesn't look efficient either. Also, even though I expect the set A to be small, I want to know if there is an efficient way to do it.

Is there a way to change the output format of itertools, similar to making parameter changes using  matplotlib.rcParams for matplotlib?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide a concrete example?

Comment: @mozway A is just any set. But I made alterations on my snippets to satisfy the minimum working code requirement.

Comment: If all entries in "C" are processed later I don't see any way for optimisation for the second code variant.

Comment: You current code seems efficient enough, it all depends on the real-life use. For sure if you have thousands of combinations and thousands in B, this won't be efficient. Use a `set` for B.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Well, I am also asking if itertools has a function like matplotlib.rcParam, where I can change the default output to list of lists rather than list of tuples.

Comment: @C.Koca No, it hasn't. Usually there is no need for something else than tuples as result of the combinatoric operations.